# Selecting rows where there are at least X rows with some values in a column via sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

Say I have the following data:

```
|bookID|data|
|1|a|
|1|b|
|1|c|
|2|x|
|2|y|
|3|t|
```

I want to select all the books that have at least X rows.  So if X=3 then I'd only get all the rows with bookID=1.  If X=2 then I'd only get all the rows with bookID=1 or bookID=2, etc.

Can I do this with SQLite3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example will get all books that have 3 or more rows.

```
  SELECT * FROM Books WHERE BookID IN
     (SELECT BookID FROM Books GROUP BY BookID HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3)
```

Comment: I don't have SQLite on this computer to test it, but it should work.  What results do you see?

Comment: 1,a (newline) 1,b (newline) 1,c (newline) --- wierd eh!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it by JOINing a subquery:

```
SELECT bookID FROM books
    JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS book_count,bookID FROM books GROUP BY bookID)
        USING (bookID)
    WHERE book_count >= 2
    GROUP BY bookID
```

[Larry Lustig’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972949/selecting-rows-where-there-are-at-least-x-rows-with-some-values-in-a-column-via-s/3973062#3973062) is much less verbose (and probably faster, too).

Comment: I wish I could mark both answers as correct.  Larry Lustig's most certainly works, however, it is limited to only having a single index.  This solution allows you to have multiple indexes and I ended up having to use this one for another, similar, problem.